# Search indexed array and return full array if matches found in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of arrays :

```
var arr = [ 
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ],
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ],
[ 'AAAA.12', 'S12' ],
[ 'AAAA.13', 'S13' ],
[ 'AAAA.14', 'S14' ] ]
```

I want to search the array values if any matches found i want to return whole array.

If im searching like `10` then it should check for array values if matches found (So the match is `AAAA.10`) then it should return whole array like this: `[[ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ], [ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ]]`.

I tried with the code below but its not working :

```
console.log(arr.find('10'));
```

Please help me to achieve the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `forEach` and `find`

```js
var arr = [
  ['AAAA.3', 'S3'],
  ['AAAA.4', 'S4'],
  ['AAAA.5', 'S5'],
  ['AAAA.6', 'S6'],
  ['AAAA.7', 'S7'],
  ['AAAA.8', 'S8'],
  ['AAAA.9', 'S9'],
  ['AAAA.10', 'S10'],
  ['AAAA.10', 'S11'],
  ['AAAA.12', 'S12'],
  ['AAAA.13', 'S13'],
  ['AAAA.14', 'S14']
];
var arr1 = [];

function a(str) {
  arr.forEach(e => {
    e.find(x => {
      if (x.includes(str)) {
        arr1.push(e)
      }
    })
  })
}
a('10');
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the first item in the nested array at `.` and use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like this:

```js
let arr=[['AAAA.3','S3'],['AAAA.4','S4'],['AAAA.5','S5'],['AAAA.6','S6'],['AAAA.7','S7'],['AAAA.8','S8'],['AAAA.9','S9'],['AAAA.10','S10'],['AAAA.10','S11'],['AAAA.12','S12'],['AAAA.13','S13'],['AAAA.14','S14']]

let result = arr.filter(a => a[0].split('.')[1] === "10")

console.log(result)
```

If you have support for [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you can do:

```
arr.filter(([key]) => key.split('.')[1] === "10")
```

**Update**:

If you want to search both indexes, you can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var arr=[['AAAA.3','S3'],['AAAA.4','S4'],['AAAA.5','S5'],['AAAA.6','S6'],['AAAA.7','S7'],['AAAA.8','S8'],['AAAA.9','S9'],['AAAA.10','S10'],['AAAA.10','S11'],['AAAA.12','S12'],['AAAA.13','S13'],['AAAA.14','S14']]

function getResults(arr, search){
  return arr.filter(a => a[0].includes(search) || a[1].includes(search))
}

console.log(getResults(arr, "10"))
console.log(getResults(arr, "S1"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.find` on each nested array to check if it contains the required string then accumulate the results using `Array.reduce`:

```js
var arr = [ [ 'AAAA.3', 'S3' ],
[ 'AAAA.4', 'S4' ],
[ 'AAAA.5', 'S5' ],
[ 'AAAA.6', 'S6' ],
[ 'AAAA.7', 'S7' ],
[ 'AAAA.8', 'S8' ],
[ 'AAAA.9', 'S9' ],
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ],
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ],
[ 'AAAA.12', 'S12' ],
[ 'AAAA.13', 'S13' ],
[ 'AAAA.14', 'S14' ] ];

function searchStr(search){
  const output = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => {
   let arr = ele.find(str => str.includes(search));
   return arr ? acc.concat(ele) : acc;
  }, []);  
  return output;
}
console.log(searchStr("10"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkNum(arr, num) {
    return arr.filter(ele => ele[0].split('.')[1] === String(num))
}
checkNum(arr, 10);
```

Comment: `num` you have mentioned is string. The search val may be anything

Comment: I dont want to split, user will search like `AA` or `S1` or anything

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```js
var arr = [ [ 'AAAA.3', 'S3' ],
[ 'AAAA.4', 'S4' ],
[ 'AAAA.5', 'S5' ],
[ 'AAAA.6', 'S6' ],
[ 'AAAA.7', 'S7' ],
[ 'AAAA.8', 'S8' ],
[ 'AAAA.9', 'S9' ],
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ],
[ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ],
[ 'AAAA.12', 'S12' ],
[ 'AAAA.13', 'S13' ],
[ 'AAAA.14', 'S14' ] ];


function search(index){
  for(i = 0; i<=arr.length-1; i++){
    if(arr[i].indexOf(index)>-1){
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
 }
 
 search("AAAA.10");
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the elements in your inner array will be string values, you can join them and do a string search.

```js
var arr = [ [ 'AAAA.3', 'S3' ], [ 'AAAA.4', 'S4' ], [ 'AAAA.5', 'S5' ], [ 'AAAA.6', 'S6' ], [ 'AAAA.7', 'S7' ], [ 'AAAA.8', 'S8' ], [ 'AAAA.9', 'S9' ], [ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ], [ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ], [ 'AAAA.12', 'S12' ], [ 'AAAA.13', 'S13' ], [ 'AAAA.14', 'S14' ] ];

const searchValue = '10';

const output = arr.filter((item) => item.join('||').includes(searchValue) );
console.log(output)
```

If you have objects or you prefer a nested loop, you can also try something like this:

```js
var arr = [ [ 'AAAA.3', 'S3' ], [ 'AAAA.4', 'S4' ], [ 'AAAA.5', 'S5' ], [ 'AAAA.6', 'S6' ], [ 'AAAA.7', 'S7' ], [ 'AAAA.8', 'S8' ], [ 'AAAA.9', 'S9' ], [ 'AAAA.10', 'S10' ], [ 'AAAA.10', 'S11' ], [ 'AAAA.12', 'S12' ], [ 'AAAA.13', 'S13' ], [ 'AAAA.14', 'S14' ] ];

const searchValue = '10';

const output = arr.filter((item) => item.some((value) => value.includes(searchValue) ) );
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to return a new array and inside the `filter` call back check if the inner elements ends with matching value & use `endsWith` for that.

You can use `includes` if you want to get array of elements which `includes` the `val` at any position

Also note this will return if both the element inside the nested array have matching character but if you use `||` instead of `&&` it will also return `['AAAA.10', 'S11']`

```js
var arr = [
  ['AAAA.3', 'S3'],
  ['AAAA.4', 'S4'],
  ['AAAA.5', 'S5'],
  ['AAAA.6', 'S6'],
  ['AAAA.7', 'S7'],
  ['AAAA.8', 'S8'],
  ['AAAA.9', 'S9'],
  ['AAAA.10', 'S10'],
  ['AAAA.10', 'S11'],
  ['AAAA.12', 'S12'],
  ['AAAA.13', 'S13'],
  ['AAAA.14', 'S14']
]

function findNestArray(val) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    if (item[0].endsWith(val)) {
      return item
    }
  })
}
console.log(findNestArray('10'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest one:

```
var result = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item[0].includes(10);
})

console.log(result);
```

The **filter** method checks every item of an array. Then returns the item according to the given function's return value. The filter method pass every item as the argument to the given function. If the function returns true, the item is selected. The includes method checks if the string contains 10. You can use `item[0].endsWith("10")` to check **10** at last position.